# ELF-Editing: Replacing function in it's own section with different function

Tags: linker, elf, objcopy

I have a .o object file which has a function that other functions in that same file are calling. That function is in it's own section and not exported. I need to replace this function with my own implementation. My own implementation needs external symbols aswell. I thought about simply patching that section so it calls an address that's placed at some location (so the old function is effectively just transfering control to my code), then I only need to add some kind of reference/relocation information so the linker knows that it needs to place the address of the function at that location (it looks like that's how it's done for all the other "imports"). But how do I do this using tools like objcopy, ld, gcc, and nm? Unfortunately I can't really use any additional tools (except for those present on a normal linux machine like sed, awk, dd and so on). I can see that the other imported symbols are listed in the symtab without an address and so on, but I can't see how they are referred to.

The output of `readelf -Ws` is

```
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 190 entries:
   Num:    Value  Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND
     1: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   57
     2: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   58
     3: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   59
     4: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   61
     5: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   62
     6: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   64
     7: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   66
     8: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   68
     9: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   70
    10: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   72
    11: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   74
    12: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   76
    13: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   78
    14: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   80
    15: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   82
    16: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   84
    17: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   86
    18: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   88
    19: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   90
    20: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   92
    21: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   94
    22: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   96
    23: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   98
    24: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT  100
    25: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT  102
    26: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT  104
    27: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT  105
    28: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT  107
    29: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT  109
    30: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT  111
    31: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT  113
    32: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT  115
    33: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT  117
    34: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT  119
    35: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT  121
    36: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT  123
    37: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT  125
    38: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT  126
    39: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT  128
    40: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT  130
    41: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT  132
    42: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT  134
    43: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT  136
    44: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT  138
    45: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT  140
    46: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT  142
    47: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT  144
    48: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT  146
    49: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT  148
    50: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT  150
    51: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT  152
    52: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT  154
    53: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT  156
    54: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT  158
    55: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT  160
    56: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT  162
    57: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT  164
    58: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT  166
    59: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT  168
    60: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    1
    61: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    2
    62: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    3
    63: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    4
    64: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    5
    65: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    6
    66: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    7
    67: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    8
    68: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    9
    69: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   10
    70: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   11
    71: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   12
    72: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   13
    73: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   14
    74: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   15
    75: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   16
    76: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   17
    77: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   18
    78: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   19
    79: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   20
    80: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   21
    81: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   22
    82: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   23
    83: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   24
    84: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   25
    85: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   26
    86: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   27
    87: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   28
    88: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   29
    89: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   30
    90: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   31
    91: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   32
    92: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   33
    93: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   34
    94: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   35
    95: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   36
    96: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   37
    97: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   38
    98: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   39
    99: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   40
   100: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   41
   101: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   42
   102: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   43
   103: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   44
   104: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   45
   105: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   46
   106: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   47
   107: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   48
   108: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   49
   109: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   50
   110: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   51
   111: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   52
   112: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   53
   113: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   54
   114: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   55
   115: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   56
   116: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT  170
   117: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT  171
   118: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT  172
   119: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT  174
   120: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND wpabuf_put
   121: 00000004    30 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   64 eap_peer_get_eap_method
   122: 00000004    29 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   66 eap_peer_get_methods
   123: 00000008    65 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   68 eap_peer_get_type
   124: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND ets_strcmp
   125: 00000008    52 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   72 eap_get_phase2_type
   126: 00000010   136 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   74 eap_get_phase2_types
   127: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND pvPortMalloc
   128: 00000008    51 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   76 eap_peer_method_alloc
   129: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND pvPortZalloc
   130: 00000008    24 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   78 eap_peer_method_free
   131: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND vPortFree
   132: 0000000c    99 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   80 eap_peer_method_register
   133: 00000008    48 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   82 eap_peer_unregister_methods
   134: 00000010    42 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   84 eap_peer_register_methods
   135: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND eap_peer_tls_register
   136: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND eap_peer_mschapv2_register
   137: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND eap_peer_peap_register
   138: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND eap_peer_ttls_register
   139: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND g_ic
   140: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND ieee80211_output_pbuf
   141: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND ets_memset
   142: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND ets_memcpy
   143: 00000008    59 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   92 wpa2_sm_alloc_eapol
   144: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND pbuf_alloc
   145: 00000020   145 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   96 eap_sm_build_identity_resp
   146: 00000000     5 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  125 eap_get_config
   147: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND os_printf_plus
   148: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND eap_msg_alloc
   149: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND eap_update_len
   150: 00000010    79 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  100 eap_sm_send_eapol
   151: 00000034   454 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  102 eap_sm_process_request
   152: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND wpabuf_free
   153: 0000001c   188 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  105 wpa2_sm_rx_eapol
   154: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND wpabuf_alloc_copy
   155: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND wpa_set_pmk
   156: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND ets_bzero
   157: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND ets_strncpy
   158: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND wifi_get_macaddr
   159: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND tls_init
   160: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND tls_deinit
   161: 00000004    37 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  126 eap_get_config_identity
   162: 00000004    37 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  128 eap_get_config_password
   163: 00000004    51 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  130 eap_get_config_password2
   164: 00000004    39 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  132 eap_get_config_new_password
   165: 00000004    63 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  134 eap_get_config_blob
   166: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND ets_strncmp
   167: 00000048   164 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  136 wifi_station_set_wpa2_enterprise_auth
   168: 00000004    36 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  138 wifi_station_set_enterprise_cert_key
   169: 00000004    21 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  140 wifi_station_clear_enterprise_cert_key
   170: 00000004    16 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  142 wifi_station_set_enterprise_ca_cert
   171: 00000004    11 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  144 wifi_station_clear_enterprise_ca_cert
   172: 00000024   109 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  146 wifi_station_set_enterprise_identity
   173: 00000010    40 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  148 wifi_station_clear_enterprise_identity
   174: 00000024   109 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  150 wifi_station_set_enterprise_username
   175: 00000010    40 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  152 wifi_station_clear_enterprise_username
   176: 00000024   103 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  154 wifi_station_set_enterprise_password
   177: 00000010    40 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  156 wifi_station_clear_enterprise_password
   178: 00000024   103 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  158 wifi_station_set_enterprise_new_password
   179: 00000010    40 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  160 wifi_station_clear_enterprise_new_password
   180: 00000004     8 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  162 wifi_station_set_enterprise_disable_time_check
   181: 00000004     8 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  164 wifi_station_get_enterprise_disable_time_check
   182: 00000004     8 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  166 wpa2_enterprise_set_user_get_time
   183: 00000004    28 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  168 wpa2_get_time
   184: 00000004    36 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  138 wifi_station_set_cert_key
   185: 00000004    21 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  140 wifi_station_clear_cert_key
   186: 00000024   109 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  146 wifi_station_set_identity
   187: 00000010    40 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  148 wifi_station_clear_identity
   188: 00000024   109 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  150 wifi_station_set_username
   189: 00000010    40 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  152 wifi_station_clear_username
```

and `readelf -t` says this about the section/function I need to modify:

There are 179 section headers, starting at offset 0x96b0:

```
Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name
       Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES   Lk Inf Al
       Flags
...
  [113] .text.eap_peer_config_deinit
       PROGBITS        00000000 000dd0 000868 00   0   0  4
       [00000006]: ALLOC, EXEC
  [114] .rela.text.eap_peer_config_deinit
       RELA            00000000 005d68 000000 0c  176 113  4
       [00000040]: INFO LINK
```

I had to cut the output as I reached the character limit.

Comment: http://xyproblem.info may be relevant here. What you are asking for is possible but _quite complicated_, and there might be easier ways to achieve your _real_ goal.

Comment: @EmployedRussian There is a library that is leaking memory. That library is only distributed as .o file and the author is not maintaining it anymore. The function I want to modify is basically calling free on the first member of a struct and then zeroing out that struct. I need to call free on the other members of the struct aswell before it's all zeroed out.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a .o object file which has a function that other functions in that same file are calling. That function is in it's own section and not exported.

> The function I want to modify is basically calling free on the first member of a struct and then zeroing out that struct. I need to call free on the other members of the struct as well before it's all zeroed out.

The simplest solution is to remove the function from the `.o` file with `objcopy --remove-section ... --remove-relocations ...`, and add your own implementation in a separate `.o`.

That's much simpler than editing existing `.o` to "splice in" different implementation, and appears to satisfy your requirements.

Comment: I think there is an issue with that: The same .o (but in another section/function) is calling that function. It is not exported as a symbol so removing it would just produce illegal jumps in that case?

Comment: @J.Doe I don't know what you mean by "not an exported symbol" `.o`s don't export any symbols anyway. What is the output from `readelf -Ws foo.o`?

Comment: Sorry, "not an exported symbol" means "not a symbol". I added the output of that command above (it's not in there). I also added the relevant output of `readelf -t`, the function I need to modify is eap_peer_config_deinit. That function is just a helper function which is called by other functions in that `.o`, it is not meant to be called from outside. Is there any chance I can throw in an external symbol for that function? I have reverse engineered it and could write a complete (proper) replacement, just need to get it in there somehow.

Comment: Any additional idea on what I could do?